# How ng-message is connected to model, and how can I show the message using ng-message?

Tags: angularjs

[In this plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/T2t5fxlj82GOZ1pcMqcs?p=preview) the objective is to show an error message based on validation in the controller (instead of the built-ins `required` or `min-length`). The message error does not display when the ng-message-exp is set.

Any idea on how to make this work or better how `ng-message` actually works which is tied to the error or model?

HTML

```
<body ng-app="ngMessagesExample" ng-controller="ctl">
  
  <form name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="submitForm(myForm)">
    <label>
      This field is only valid when 'aaa' is entered  
      <input type="text"
             ng-model="data.field1"
             name="field1" />
    </label>
    <div ng-messages="myForm.field1.$error" style="color:red">
        <div ng-message-exp="validationError">this is the error</div>
    </div>
  
  <br/><br/>
  <button style="float:left" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('ngMessagesExample', ['ngMessages']);

app.controller('ctl', function ($scope) {
  
  $scope.submitForm = function(form) {
    
    if (form.field1.$modelValue != 'aaa') {
        $scope.validationError = true;
        console.log('show error');
    }
    else {
        $scope.validationError = false;
        console.log('don\'t show error');
    }
  };
  
  
});
```

Comment: It looks like you're overcomplicating things.  Why bother with ripping out the form element's `$modelValue`?  Why not just check the `ng-model` the `$scope.data.field1`?

Comment: even if I do that, the error message is not displayed

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your main `ng-messages` argument is tied to `myForm.field1.$error`, but you never actually add an error to the `form.field1.$error`.  So in your controller, just manually add an error to the `$error` object via `$setValidity(field, isValid)`:

```
if ($scope.data.field1 != 'aaa') {
    form.field1.$setValidity('validationError', false);
    // Angular will make form.field1.$error.validationError = true;
}
else {
    form.field1.$setValidity('validationError', true);
    // Angular will make form.field1.$error.validationError = false;
}
```

Then, you can just have the `ng-message` directive do its work.  The child elements that provide `ng-message` are evaluated as properties of their parent `ng-messages` already (note the extra `s`).  So typically, this is used with the parent being the form element's `$error` object and the inner children are the  properties like `$error.required` or in your case `$error.validationError`.  No need for `ng-message-exp` here:

```
<div ng-messages="myForm.field1.$error" style="color:red">
    <div ng-message="validationError">this is the error</div>
</div>
```

[Fixed plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7lVVnKSqr7qE86J4K0ze?p=preview)

Answer (score 23):

The more proper way to do this in controller is to use $setValidity

```
if(a !== b){
    form.inputName.$setValidity('custom-err', false);
} else {
    form.inputName.$setValidity('custom-err', true);
}

form.$setSubmitted();
```

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this should work - you can also add code as well as the comments in the code itself 
- in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question. This is especially important for an older question and the questions that already have answers.

Comment: see the below Pablo Sanchez Manzano answer - thats exactly what i mean. The purpose is to use native angular methods and not to invent the wheel

Comment: In my case I missed "form.$setSubmitted". That method triggers ng-messages functionality and then it shows the text. Althought, I still do not understand why "form.$validate()" function does not work either.

Answer (score 10):

The Dmitry K's answer it's excellent.

I´m going to expand the answer.

```
//Function before show your form:
vm.showForm(form){
        form.$setPristine();
        form.$setUntouched();
        form.myFieldName.$setValidity('myCustomValidationName', false);

        //More code...
}

//funtion to validate field on "ng-change"
vm.validateField(form){

    if(xxxx == yyy) //Make your own validation{
       form.myFieldName.$setValidity('myCustomValidationName', true);
    }else{
       form.myFieldName.$setValidity('myCustomValidationName', false);
    }

}
```

And the relevant HTML code:

```
<form name="myFormName" novalidate>
    <md-input-container class="md-block">
        <label>myField</label>
        <input ng-model="ctrl.myFieldName" name="myFieldName" ng-change="ctrl.validateField(myFormName)" />

        <div ng-show="myFormName.myFieldName.$touched || myFormName.$submitted">
            <div ng-messages="myFormName.myFieldName.$error">
                <div ng-message="myCustomValidationName">this is the message to show</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </md-input-container>
</form>
```