# how to get the controller value to Ng-message validation?

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

I'm trying to get the value from controller to ng-message error but value doesn't come.

In ng-show I can easily bind the value to ng-show but in ng-message, I don't how to do that ...

```
<body ng-app="BlankApp" ng-cloak ng-controller="ctrl">

  <form name="exampleForm" ng-submit="exampleForm.$valid && demo()">
    <label>User Message:</label>
    <input type="text" name="userMessage" class="form-control" rows="4" ng-model="message" ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="100" required></textarea>
    <div ng-messages="submitted1 && exampleForm.userMessage.$error">
      <div ng-message=" required">This field is required</div>
      <div ng-message=" test">Message must be over 10 characters</div>
      <div ng-message="test">{{test}}</div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit"  ng-click="submitted1=true" value="Recharge"/>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">    
    angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMessages'])
    .controller('ctrl',function($scope){
      $scope.message;
      $scope.val=40;
      $scope.demo=function(){
        if($scope.val >=$scope.message)
          $scope.msg="Hello world"
      }
      else{
        $scope.test="pls enter the number 10 to 40"
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display custom error ngMessage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401663/display-custom-error-ngmessage)

Answer (score 0):

`ng-messages` directive should listen on a key/value object. And each `ng-message` is a key in the previous object. Also `test` is not a valid key in `exampleForm.userMessage.$error` object, as described in the official documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages

So you can rewrite your code something like this:

```
<div ng-if="submitted1">
    <div ng-messages="exampleForm.userMessage.$error">
        <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply mac i know ng-messages takes this required, ng-maxlength and ng-minlength all i want is pass the controller value to ng-message error is there any way for that?

Comment: You need to update the `$error` object in controller, like this: `exampleForm.userMessage.$error.customError= true;` and in the html `<div ng-message="customError">{{test}}/div>`

Comment: this question is actually a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401663/display-custom-error-ngmessage