# Angular formly validation for amount field is not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I am trying to display the message using formly template and validator.

Template has :

```
 <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
 <div ng-message="amountValid">Please enter valid amount</div>
```

and using formly, I am calling the validator to set this message.

required message working fine using templateOption - required.

In case of inline validation for validator its not validating correct condition. It just display error when I start typing any random value.

Can you please help? Thanks.

```
"templateOptions": {
          required: true
 },
 validators: {
          amountValid: '$viewValue > availableAmount'
 }
```

Note : availableAmount is getting populated from service. I also tried by giving message in validator but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue using validator as below

```
 validators: {
          amountInvalid: function($viewValue, $modelValue, scope) {
                 var disAmountValue = $modelValue || $viewValue;
                 return (disAmountValue <= txnAmount);
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$viewValue` for input elements is a string and your `availableAmount` is most probably integer. Try to parse `$viewValue` to int before comparing: `parseInt($viewValue) > availableAmount`

Comment: Thanks Slava. I tried but no success with amountValid: 'parseInt($viewValue) > 22', strange part is if I try to extract that to     function like   amountValid: function validateAmount($viewValue) {
                validateTransactionAmount($viewValue)
              }.....It not at all displaying any error message. I am returning true from this function in case of condition meet.

Comment: Try to update `$error` object in your function like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35401893/7362128